# What is the reason for partial loss of data from Android SensorManager?

Tags: android, events, delay, sensors

I am using sensors - accelerometer, compass, and gyro for a test application. 
I register for sensor events for all these sensors at DELAY_GAME. However, as soon as the screen goes off, the sensor data updates are stopped. There are outages for as long as 85 seconds. I have already taken a partial wake lock before registering for sensor events and release the lock after stoping the sensor updates.

The interesting thing is that I have noticed this behaviour on a Galaxy S3.(4.0.4). However, on other devices - Note, Galaxy Nexus and S2, there is no such behaviour.

Any pointers please ?

-Robin

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing your Sensor Listeners in a Service ? If no, you'd want to exclude them from any Activity lifecycle.